# Can I practice the flight controls outside of an online multiplayer match?

Tags: battlefield-3

Is there some way I can get practice with flying the helicopters and jets outside of a multiplayer match?

Comment: They really need to add some sort of "Sandbox" mode.  Something where you can pick the map, spawn by yourself, and practice with vehicles and parachuting and anything else!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Battlefield recently released a patch to all systems for support of a "practice" mode. There are 2 different options:

1. Find an empty server with a jet map as the current map. When you join now, there will be an unranked "practice" mode while waiting for other players to join the game. When enough people join the game, the map will reload and the actual ranked match will start
2. Do the above, but rent a server and make it private with a jet map. (completely optional, there are plenty of empty servers)

Answer (score 13):

There is a co-op level that involves flying a helicopter, but it's not the best chance to practice.

There is no way to practice flying a jet outside of a multiplayer match.

Your best bet is to attempt to find a flight training server. These are servers which have a low max player amount, instant vehicle respawn, and generally people leave you alone to practice flying, and will only dogfight with you after asking if you wish to dogfight.

Comment: Are flight training servers applicable for PS3?

Comment: @FishOfPrey Someone will have had to set one up, but I'm assuming that there'd be at least one out there somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

> Will it be possible to practice flying without having to be in an
>   active multiplayer server? Such as a large training map or something
>   of the sorts so people can hone their skills in the flying vehicles. 
>   - Giblet1
>
> Lars: Nothing in the game at launch, sadly.

source - [games.on.net interview with Lars Gustavsson](http://games.on.net/article/13978/Battlefield_3_Lars_Gustavsson_vs._games.on.net)

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no unranked servers on ps3 yet which would be needed for this.